# PythonAnywhere image not found

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

Before anyone deletes this due to the question being similar to others: Neither other questions nor the documentation got my site to work as intended.

The goal: Load images on my site

The problem: Image not found

Additional info: It works locally using `python manage.py runserver`

What I've done to try to fix it:

- I've tried to follow the staticfiles guide https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles but this didn't work because I'm not using the default uploaded files handling.
- I've tried to enter it under the PythonAnywhere > Web > static files tab but haven't been able to get that to work.
- Tried a bunch of different solutions from the PythonAnywhere forum and SO forum and none got my site to work.

The site: http://nasablogdeployment.eu.pythonanywhere.com/

All code available here: https://github.com/MarkdenToom/NASA-blog

Static files directories here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoJGH.jpg

WSGI file content: https://i.stack.imgur.com/14RIC.jpg

Comment: What did you try entering on the static files tab inside PythonAnywhere?

Comment: @GilesThomas I knew I forgot something. I added a screenshot of that and the WSGI file to the main post.

Comment: did you solve this issue? It seems the static files directories picture you uploaded says you have some static files working already?

Comment: @conrad the URL /static/admin and /static/ both work, but the /media/ does not. I assume there's an issue with the Directory, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your web app is looking for the picture in  `http://nasablogdeployment.eu.pythonanywhere.com/blog/media/thumbnails/Touchdown_Expedition_62_Returns_to_Earth_Completes_Station_Mission.jpg` while your current mapping resolves into url like that: `http://nasablogdeployment.eu.pythonanywhere.com/media/thumbnails/Touchdown_Expedition_62_Returns_to_Earth_Completes_Station_Mission.jpg`

Change your static files mapping so the `/blog/media/` points to `/home/nasablogdeployment/NASA-blog/blog/media/`

Comment: The directory was set to what you suggested I'd change, but changing the url from `/media/` to `/blog/media/` did the trick. Thank you for the help!